# jQuery add class to radio button is checked with specific label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I currently use jQuery to add/remove a class when a radio button is selected.
The problem is that by default on page load a radio button is already checked. But in that case the class is not added, only when selecting another radio button.

How can I make this work, so that by default the class is already add to the radio button that is checked?

jQuery:

```
<script>
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").find(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").addClass("selected");
  }
  else
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="21" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text">Text</span>
        <span class="addon-price">Text</span>
        </label>
      </span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="22" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text">Text</span>
        <span class="addon-price">Text</span>
        </label>
      </span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="23" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price">Text</span>
        </label>
      </span>



<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="17" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price">Text</span>
        </label>
      </span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
        </label>
      </span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="2" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
        </label>
      </span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
        </label>
      </span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="4" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
        <span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
        <span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
        </label>
      </span>
```

Comment: manually call the change event `jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").find(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
  if ($(this).is(':checked')){
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").addClass("selected");
  }
  else
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
}).change();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.trigger('change')` to trigger change event on elements and the event handler will be executed.

The class of the previously checked elements have to be removed before adding new class.

```
jQuery('.checkbox-radio').change(function () {
    // Remove all classes first
    $('.radio-inline.selected').removeClass('selected');

    // Add class to the closest element of the selected radio
    $('.checkbox-radio:checked').closest('.radio-inline')
        .addClass('selected');
}).trigger('change');
```

```js
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
  $('.selected').removeClass('selected');
  $(".checkbox-radio:checked").closest(".radio-inline")
    .addClass("selected");
}).trigger('change');
```

```css
span.option {
  display: block;
}
.selected {
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="21" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text">Text</span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="22" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text">Text</span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="23" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>



<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="17" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="2" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="4" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code, but that does not add the class to the radio buttons that are already checked when the page is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").find(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").addClass("selected");
  } else
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
}).change();//manually call change event here
```

```css
.selected{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="21" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text">Text</span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="22" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text">Text</span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="23" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>



<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="17" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="2" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="4" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
```

1. Manually call the change event using `.change()` or `.trigger('change')`.

Answer (score 0):

You should [trigger(eventType)](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the change event on page load.

> Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

```
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
    //Existing code
}).trigger('change'); //Fire the event on page load
```

[`.change()`](https://api.jquery.com/change/#change) can also be use as its shorthand for `.trigger( "change" )`

```js
jQuery(".checkbox-radio").change(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").find(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").addClass("selected");
  } else
    $(this).closest(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected");
}).trigger('change'); //Fire the change event
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="21" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text">Text</span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="22" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text">Text</span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>

<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-5"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[5]" value="23" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>



<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="17" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price">Text</span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="1" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="2" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="3" checked="checked" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
<span class="option">
      <label class="radio-inline conf-option-1"><input type="radio" class="checkbox-radio" name="configoption[1]" value="4" onclick="prodconfrecalcsummary()">
        <i class="icon-addon"></i>
        <span class="addon-qty"></span>
<span class="addon-text"> Text </span>
<span class="addon-price"> Text </span>
</label>
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried your code, but that does not add the class to the radio buttons that are already checked when the page is loaded.

Comment: @HenkZ, Are you using any plugin?

Comment: No, I added your code right into the template file.

Comment: When removing the line:   $(this).closest("div").find(".radio-inline").removeClass("selected"); It works, but in that case the class will not be removed when selecting another radio button.